# Is there a way to conflict-merge past commits of a same branch?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-checkout

So here's the deal:

There was a homework file I was working on. I `checkout` ed the repo into a school computer, and added comments to that repo. But before merging the comments, I made changes in part of my source code. When I merged the two branches, I used `git checkout --ours`, when I should have saved the changed part of branch A and the comment part from branch B. What is worse, I even made more changes after the merge.

So it went essentially like this

```
Source code          Source code  
-----------          ----------- 
Part A         ->    Part A Change source         
-----------          -----------  
Part B               Part B         
-----------          -----------   

                     Source code  
                     ----------- 
               ->    Part A         
                     -----------  
                     Part B Comments         
                     -----------
```

This should have merged into

```
Source code        
-----------        
Part A Change source  And then More changes      
-----------          
Part B Comments                
-----------
```

But it became

```
Source code        
-----------        
Part A Change source  And then more changes    
-----------          
Part B                 
-----------
```

Now, I tried making a merge conflict by `git merge 6883dbbb`(tag of comment) But it showed

```
Already up to date.
```

I've seen many responses suggesting checking out the branch. However, I want a partial reversal of a single file. Because I added (and want to keep) more changes after the initial merge, I can't checkout to the point of merge. Are there any suggestions to this problem? Thanks.

```
| *   commit 4a51c9ac25e88f29b57d345ec294413e0969f1b6
| |\  Merge: 98b00f5 688a3db
| | | Author: 
| | | Date:   Tue May 7 00:51:21 2019 +0900
| | | 
| | |     complete merge
| | | 
| | * commit 688a3dbbbf7dab71703bb3107f0d4451cf85da88
| | | Author: 
| | | Date:   Sun May 5 03:02:39 2019 +0900
| | | 
| | |     HW4 report initial finish part 1 & comments
| | | 
| * | commit 98b00f5db8844251b13dc98ac5d6314d4fc4180f
| | | Author: 
| | | Date:   Tue May 7 00:39:35 2019 +0900
| | | 
| | |     confirm everything works
| | | 
| * | commit a89a77a64336dad49d124a2e8470b84764b9660d
| | | Author:  
| | | Date:   Sun May 5 17:08:26 2019 +0900
| | | 
| | |     move testcase
| | | 
| * | commit 40c4977a813088c910c54002cd9ca56eb880f722
| |/  Author: 
| |   Date:   Sun May 5 17:07:01 2019 +0900
| |   
| |       fix bubble
| |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is *effectively* the same as if you had merged, and then reverted the merge.  That is, `git` thinks the commits on the branch are "accounted for", but the changes are undone.  (The difference is that the merge itself undid the changes, rather than a later commit, but the effect is the same.)

To fix this situation, you need to create new commits that mimic those on the branch.  The easiest way to do that is with `git rebase -f`.

The only wrinkle is, you need to identify the commit where your branch diverged from `master` (or whatever the "upstream" branch is; we'll say `master` for the sake of discussion) - and the "obvious" ways to do this (like `merge-base`) won't work as you might expect since your entire branch is now reachable from `master`.  But if you know it's just a single commit, that's simple enough:

```
git checkout branch
git rebase -f HEAD^
```

Now you can merge `branch` in again.

Answer (score -1):

I would simply manually recreate the commit with comments:

```
git format-patch 6883dbbb --stdout | patch -p1
git commit -a -m 'Re-applied comments commit'
```